# using json_encode in php how to consume in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am returning data from php by json_encode
     `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
               echo json_encode($row);`
    }

now when i console log i get
{"username":"foster","sport":"tennis","latitude":"19.166901","longitude":"72.951720"}{"username":"anirudh","sport":"rugby","latitude":"19.218330","longitude":"72.978088"}

question is how do i gain access to the returned fields. its being returned as a string. When i do JSON.parse
i get an error

```
VM1115:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 85
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (form.js:43)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Please advice.

Many Thanks
Archit Wahi

Comment: paste your JSON into jsonlint.com and see if it validates. You should most likely have a comma between those two lines if that's one call and they should be encapsulated in [] or {}.

Comment: You're outputting individual JSON objects.  Build the array and then encode.

Comment: No it doesnt. as theres no seperator between them                                                                              
  Error: Parse error on line 6:
...ude": "72.951720"} { "username": "anir
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to parse the json data..Simply get it by using `data.objectname`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are creating your json you will have difficulties parsing it in js.
This is the way you should go about it.

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    $result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Which will give you a json which you can parse if required using:

```
var result = JSON.parse(thePHPresult);
```

and your JSON will look something like:

```
[{"field_1":1,"field_2":"test1"},{"field_1":2,"field_2":"test2"},{"field_1":3,"field_2":"test3"}]
```

Which is a JSON array and can be accesed as:

```js
var theJSON = [{"field_1":1,"field_2":"test1"},{"field_1":2,"field_2":"test2"},{"field_1":3,"field_2":"test3"}];

for(var i=0; i< theJSON.length; i++)
{
 console.log(theJSON[i].field_2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the rows to an array and after the while, you can echo the result of json_encode(). Simple rows echoed after each are not valid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Do you get the error when you just have one result from the database or is it when you have multiple rows?

If you store all your rows in an array and then echo json encode the array, will that solve your issue?

Comment: This isn't much of an answer.  Post questions as comments to the original question.